# Complex String Conversion to integer

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception, string-formatting, string-conversion

I am trying to convert an array that holds string values into integer values, I have used the `parseInt` function but get an error message (java.lang.NullPointerException) at the point of execution. My code snippet is below

```
public int NumberOfColumns;
public int[][]CMax,CMin;

for (int i = 1; i < datas.length; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 1; j < NumberOfColumns+1; j++)
         {
           CMax[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(datas[i][j]);
           System.out.println(CMax[i][j]);
           System.out.println(datas[i][j]);
         }
     }
```

I have a feeling that I am getting this error message because my data array contains some characters like "-". Examples of some values stored in my data array include 0-31, 8-*, <4-7>. How can I successfully resolve this problem? Also, I need help on how to extract only the integer numbers out of these strings (e.g. 0-31). I will like to store the upper limit (e.g. 31) into a separate integer array and the lower limit(e.g. 0) into another integer array.

Below is an extract of some of the values in my data array.

```
<0-15> <0-7>
<0-15> <0-7>
<0-15> <0-7>
<32-47> <0-7>
<32-47> <0-7>
```

Comment: What is `NumberOfColumns`? where is the code that fills your arrays? Variables should start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: please post `datas` 2D array with actual data

Comment: Are `CMax` and `datas` correctly initialized ?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in the comments, the only possibilities for a NPE is one of the below ones are null.

- datas
- datas[i]
- CMax
- CMax[i]
- NumberOfColumns

Hopefully you can get the program corrected by looking at those.

Note: Java array index starts with 0, not 1.

Comment: _"Have you verified that all the values in `datas[i][j]` are convertible to integer?"_ That would yield to `NumberFormat` exception, not a `NullPointer` one

Comment: Exactly... that's where I was trying to take him to.... When he try to find the exact values in the array elements, I assumed he will noticed that there are null values as well. (That's why I did not even ask for the line number of NPE).

Comment: But `null` values will also make `parseInt()` to throw a `NumberFormat` exception :). The only thing that can throw the `NPE` in the snippet of code he provides is that `datas` is `null` or `CMax` is `null` (or both).

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that. Thanks for pointing. Let me update the answer to match that.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that datas[datas.length-1][NumberOfColumns] == null.

A little advice: iterate your indexes from 0 to N-1 (inclusive), and not from 1 to N.